# Software updates for 13.04

Tags: 13.04, update-manager

I am running 13.04.

I opened Software Updater. It started OK and then came up with the following message: "**Software updates are no longer provided for Ubuntu 13.04** " followed by "To stay secure, you should upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10"

Is this an error? What is happening?

Please can someone explain what is going on. I have never had this in any previous edition of Ubuntu and it has always been possible to run and update a system two releases back, let alone LTS versions.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/ubuntu-13-04-end-of-life-january-27

Does that cover it? Support period for non-LTS releases was changed recently.

Comment: OK so I now find that this was decided last year, but remain very uncomfortable with a 9-month cycle. Am seriously considering whether to stay with Ubuntu, but thanks for the advice. As for announcing it in a blog somewhere: there really isn't sufficient time to read every blog. It would have been more helpful to change policy from 14.04with a longer period for LTSs (as agreed) and (say) two releases for others. The EOL date should be stated prominently on upgrading and in "about" to help us all. I note from the minutes that users weren't consulted.

Answer (score 1):

Support for Ubuntu 13.04 has ended on 2014-01-27. Please upgrade to a more recent version as soon as possible.